# .htaccess nao funciona a regra

Tags: htaccess

Teria como ficar minhas urls assim?

```
produtos/nome-categoria
ptodutos/nome-categoria/nome-subcategorias
```

Pois não estou conseguindo fazer, olhem como estou fazendo a regra no .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
    #aqui criamos uma condição para que os arquivos sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #aqui criamos uma condição para que diretórios sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #aqui definimos onde começa a base das regras

    #fix rules
    RewriteRule ^pagina-inicial/?$ index.php [NC,L]       
   RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1&id_subcategoria=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

assim só o ptodutos/nome-categoria/nome-subcategorias funcina

Answer (score 0):

Tem que fazer uma parte do regex seja opcional.

Para isso, usamos um `(?:`[grupo](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/modernosos-fantasma.html#3_5_2)`)` com o [quantificador](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/opcional.html#2_2_1) `?`.

```py
^produtos/([^/]*)(?:/(.*))?
#                ^^^^^^^^^^
#                 opcional
```

**.htaccess**

```py
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^pagina-inicial/?$ index.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^produtos/([^/]*)(?:/(.*))? categorias.php?id_categoria=$1&id_subcategoria=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Teste no:

- https://regex101.com/r/CjKPun/1

Ou veja funcionando:

- http://mariano.uphero.com/217354/pagina-inicial
- http://mariano.uphero.com/217354/produtos/nome-categoria
- http://mariano.uphero.com/217354/produtos/nome-categoria/sub-categoria

Comment: para acessar asssim **produtos/nome-categoria** funcionou

mais 
quando acesso assim **produtos/nome-categoria/sub-categoria** nao funciona

`código`RewriteRule ^produtos/([^/]*)(?:/(.*))/([^/]*)(?:/(.*))? subcategorias.php?id_categoria=$1&id_subcategoria=$2 [NC,L,QSA]`código`

Comment: @Wagner Pode ver os exemplos que eu adicionei.